# MS access VBA - query exclude

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am struggling with setting up a query that excludes certain values from a table.
For a better understanding - the database is created in the context of clinical trials and I want select sites via a combobox that do not yet participate in a study while they might or might not already participate in another one.

Here is the approach:

tbl_site - contains a unique "site_ID" and "site_country"

tbl_study - contanis a unique "study_ID"

tbl_init - Whenever a site is participating in a study, an entry is generated with a unique "init_ID", the corresponding "site_ID" and "study_ID".

The query should select all sites from "tbl_site", that do not yet have a matching entry in "tbl_ini" with a defined "study_id". I understand, that I should be able to achieve this using LEFT JOINS.

```
SELECT tbl_site.site_ID, tbl_site.site_country, tbl_init.study_ID
FROM tbl_site LEFT JOIN tbl_init ON tbl_site.site_ID = tbl_init.site_ID
WHERE (((tbl_init.study_ID) Not In ([Form]![frm_init]![study_ID]))) AND ((tbl_site.site_country)=[cbo_country]))
```

However, it seems the exclusion of values does only affect the 1st value from tbl_init. For instance: If I have 2 sites from US and 2 sites from UK, all the UK sites and one of the US-sites are already part of study 1. Running the query for study 1 will in fact exclude the participating site from US, but will still show me all the sites from UK (I guess that is depending on the initial sorting in the source tables).
In the end I also need to add "Not Null" to add all sites, that are not participating in any study yet.

**EDIT: Here is an Example:**

1. I have "Study X" and "Study Y" and no site is allocated yet => The query for both study_IDs shows all sites in tbl_site ("A" - "E")
2. After adding sites "A", "B" and "C" to "Study X", the query for "Study X" results in "D" and "E", which is good so far.
3. After adding Site "D" and "E" to "Study Y", the query for "Study Y" shows sites "A" to "C".

Now comes the tricky part

4. I add site "C" - which already participates in "Study X" - to "Study Y". If I now query for "Study X", "C" appears again as there is one entry in the tbl_init, where the study_ID matches "C" but the study_ID unequals "Study X" - and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are passing two parameters to the query, *Country* and *Study Id* and you’re looking to list all sites in that country that do **not** participate in the given study id.

```
PARAMETERS [cbo_country] Text ( 255 ), [Forms]![frm_init]![study_ID] Text ( 255 );
SELECT tbl_site.site_ID, tbl_site.site_country, tbl_init.study_ID
FROM tbl_site LEFT JOIN tbl_init ON tbl_site.site_ID = tbl_init.site_ID
WHERE (((tbl_site.site_country)=[cbo_country]) AND ((tbl_site.site_ID) Not In (SELECT tbl_init.site_ID FROM tbl_init WHERE (((tbl_init.study_ID)=[Forms]![frm_init]![study_ID])))));
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Problem is: This way I am not getting all sites, which do not participate in the given study but all sites that are participating in other studies. As one site might participate in several studies, sites are not excluded from the list anymore as soon as they also participate in another study - or to put it in a general context - as soon as this ID is present in more than one entry.

Comment: Working like a charm. Much obliged!